# How to display state information on the map

Tags: d3.js

I have made a map of canada in geojson..
I am really new to d3 and geojson.
I want to display state information on the map.
how should i divide the map ?

My code for the map of canada is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var w = 1560;
      var h = 900;

      var proj = d3.geo.mercator();

      var path = d3.geo.path().projection(proj);

      var t = proj.translate(); // the projection's default translation
      var s = proj.scale() // the projection's default scale

      var map = d3.select("#vis").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

      var axes = map.append("svg:g").attr("id", "axes");

      var xAxis = axes.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", t[0])
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", t[0])
        .attr("y2", h);

      var yAxis = axes.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", t[1])
        .attr("x2", w)
        .attr("y2", t[1]);

      var uk = map.append("svg:g").attr("id", "uk");

      d3.json("uk.json", function (json) {
          uk.selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr("d", path);
      });

      function redraw() {
          // d3.event.translate (an array) stores the current translation from the parent SVG element
          // t (an array) stores the projection's default translation
          // we add the x and y vales in each array to determine the projection's new translation
          var tx = t[0] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[0];
          var ty = t[1] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[1];
          proj.translate([tx, ty]);

          // now we determine the projection's new scale, but there's a problem:
          // the map doesn't 'zoom onto the mouse point'
          proj.scale(s * d3.event.scale);

          // redraw the map
          uk.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

          // redraw the x axis
          xAxis.attr("x1", tx).attr("x2", tx);

          // redraw the y axis
          yAxis.attr("y1", ty).attr("y2", ty);
      }
  </script>
```

could you please tell me what should i do ?

please guide me.

i am really new to d3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying state information on the map with geojson and d3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278575/displaying-state-information-on-the-map-with-geojson-and-d3)

Comment: little changed one..didnt know..how to proceed